# My if statements are not carrying over to the final output. One changes the string and the others don't but seem like they should. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, string, while-loop, user-input

I'm trying to take a user input string and manipulate it in various ways to make it better, such as adding a '?' if there is a question indicator present as the first word or to replace a typo such as a ',' at the end of a sentence with a '.'

When I test each individual part it seems to work correctly, and at once point everything worked when adding a string to sentence_maker('something like this') but then I added the while loop to enable user input and it seems the if statements are not each applying their modifications to the string, it is capitalizing the first letter but doing nothing else.

I was doing a lot of noob stuff like phrase = phrase[:-1] + '.', but I kept getting typenone items in a list at the end as well.

```py
def sentence_maker(phrase):

    question_indicators = ('What', 'Where', 'When', 'Why', 'Which', 'Who', 'Whose', 'How', 'Is', 'Does')

    # if string begins wither lowercase, upper it, 2.
    if phrase[0].islower():
        return phrase[0].upper() + phrase[1:]

    # if last index in string == ',','?', delete and add '.', 1.
    if phrase[-1] in [',', '?']:
        return phrase[:-1] + '.'

    #add a '.', 1
    if phrase[-1] not in ['.','!']:
        return phrase + '.'

    # if string begins with question indicator, add a ?, 1.
    if phrase.startswith(question_indicators) and phrase.split()[-1][-1] in ['.','!',',']:
        return phrase[:-1] + '?'

results = []

while True:
    phrase = input('Enter your text here, good sir: ') 
    if phrase == '\end':
        break
    else:
        results.append(sentence_maker(phrase))
    
print(results)
```

Comment: You `return` inside each `if`. As soon as one `if` condition matches, its action will be applied and the result returned. The function ends then and there.

Comment: You need to `return` the modified string *once* at the end of the function…

Comment: you need to assign the altered phrase back to itself within every if statement. For example, `phrase = phrase[0].upper() + phrase[1:]`

then `return phrase` at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in a comment, you stop processing the phrase as soon as the first `if` statement matches.  If you want to perform all the steps, change the `return` statements e.g. into reassignments.

However, your logic seems rather inconsistent. I would refactor it to

```py
def sentence_maker(phrase):
    question_indicators = ('What', 'Where', 'When', 'Why', 'Which', 'Who', 'Whose', 'How', 'Is', 'Does')

    # if string begins wither lowercase, upper it, 2.
    phrase = phrase[0].upper() + phrase[1:]

    # if phrase ends with punctuation, remove it
    if phrase.endswith((',', '?', '.', '!')):
        phrase = phrase[:-1]

    # if string begins with question indicator, endpunc is ?
    if phrase.startswith(question_indicators):
        endpunc = '?'
    else:
        endpunc = '.'

    phrase += endpunc

    return phrase
```

The choice to force the first character to upper case even if it's unnecessary is slightly dubious, but my hunch is that avoiding the condition is faster than avoiding unnecessary uppercasing.

The other changes focus on restructuring the handling of trailing punctuation; we remove any final punctuation, then add something back.  My feeling is that this is simpler to understand and keep up to date if your requirements evolve over time.

The question indicators are somewhat problematic; you probably want to match "Whichever" and "However" when they are question indicators, but the latter often isn't; on the other hand, many words which begin with "Is" are not question indicators ("Issue", "Island", etc) - adding a space would fix those, but require you to add more words which end with "What", "Which", "Who", etc. (so "Whatever", "Whichever", etc). I also notice that "Isn't" and "Are" and its negation are missing, as well as auxiliary verbs like "Would", "Should", "Must", "Have", "Has", etc.

Comment: And "Whom", though given how few people use it correctly, perhaps you should just change it to "Who"!